# How to find all sub directories containing a particular file and then grep another file in those sub-directories?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, xargs

I have a folder containing 100 sub-directories.

`dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 ...`

Each sub-directory contains a file `simv.log`

Also, each directory either contains - `FAILED.txt` or `PASSED.txt` file.

I want to grep a pattern "ABCD" in the `simv.log` files where `FAILED.txt` is present.

I can find all directories containing FAILED.txt by using:
`find . -name "FAILED.txt" -print "%h\n"`

How can I further use this output to grep ABCD in `simv.log` file of those directories?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "FAILED.txt" -printf "%h/simv.log\0" | xargs -0 grep -F ABCD
```

should do the trick

Comment: This isn't working. I'm getting ": No such file or directory" from the piped command even though the file exists.

Comment: @Amit128 Worked fine when I tested it.

Comment: @Amit128 sounds like you have some directories that contains FAILED.txt but not simv.log.

Comment: It works, sorry for my earlier comment. There was a typo in the command I was using. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "FAILED.txt"   -printf "%h/simv.log\n"  | while read line ; do  grep ABCD -nr $line ; done;
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 (and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for more details) for how to read output of a command using a loop and see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for how to use quotes.